Se repiten los numeros aveces en la misma columna o en la fila
Buenas el siguiente codigo busco generar numeros al azar sin embargo he percatado que se repiten los numeros aveces en la misma columna o en la misma fila y lo que quiero es que no se repitan en ninguna de ellas, estaba leyendo sobre las funciones rand y mt pero en ambas opciones en algun momento se repiten y quiero es que en la tabla en ninguna fila o columna este algun repetido
/**
 * Tabla que muestre numeros aleatorios comprendidos entre 1 y 49.
 * La tabla tiene 5 filas y 7 columnas.
 */
    $posicion=0;
    $repetidos=array();

    echo "<table>";
        for($fila=1; $fila<=5 ; $fila++){
            echo "<tr>";
                for($columna=1; $columna<=7; $columna++){
                    echo "<td>"  . "&nbsp " .   "&nbsp " . $repetidos[$posicion]=comprobarRepetido($repetidos,mt_rand(1,49)) . "</td>";
                    $posicion=$posicion+1;
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";

    /**
     * Algoritmo que recorre el contenido de un array
     * y comprueba si el numero pasado por parametros
     * se encuentra contenido en este.
     */
    function comprobarRepetido($array, $numero){
        //bandera para comprobar si el numero se repite
        $repetido=false;

        //recorre el array mientras el valor no esté contenido
        for($indice=0; $indice<count($array) && $repetido==false; $indice++){
            //si el numero es igual a $valor, devuelve true
            $repetido=($array[$indice]==$numero)?true:false;
        }

        //en caso que el numero se repita, pasa por parametros un nuevo numero
        //y realiza recursividad a si misma 
        if($repetido==true)
            comprobarRepetido($array,mt_rand(1,49));
        else
            return $numero;
    }
    ?>  ```


Creas un array con el set de número que necesitas y vas sacando los números de ese array, de esta manera nunca se van a repetir. Es como ir sacando números desde una tómbola.
La función mt_rand la utilizas para obtener el índice del array (no el número en sí mismo)
$repetidos = range(1, 49); //crea un array secuencial con números desde el 1 al 49

echo "<table>";
    for($fila=1; $fila<=5 ; $fila++){
        echo "<tr>";
            for($columna=1; $columna<=7; $columna++){
                $num = mt_rand(0,count($repetidos)-1); //obtenemos el índice aleatorio
                $val = $repetidos[$num]; //el valor de dicho indice
                echo "<td>"  . "&nbsp " .   "&nbsp " . $val . "</td>";
                array_splice($repetidos, $num , 1); //lo quitamos del array
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

-- DEMO --
